# Connect to a SOAP API from Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, soap, wsdl, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

Hope you all doing well.
This question is related to Azure Data factory and SOAP API.

I get data in SOAP API in a WSDL url, for instance (http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?wsdl). And this data is to be stored in a Azure data lake through ADF. I have tried a couple of methods in online, but could not get it done.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.
Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For the SOAP API we can use generic HTTP connector.
HTTP connector is generic to retrieve data from any HTTP endpoint, e.g. to download file. Before REST connector becomes available, you may happen to use the HTTP connector to copy data from RESTful API, which is supported but less functional comparing to REST connector.

This HTTP connector is supported for the following activities:

1. Copy activity with supported source/sink matrix
2. Lookup activity

You can copy data from an HTTP source to any supported sink data store.For a list of data stores that Copy Activity supports as sources and sinks, see  here [Supported data stores and formats.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#supported-data-stores-and-formats)
Here is the reference doc for http connector  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http